# When i click on checkbox, I want to show textbox?

Tags: angular, checkbox

When I click on checkbox, I want to show my backend parameter to split as two text-boxes. I am facing difficulty, Can anyone help here.? this is coming from backend. like values as labels

template_parameter: "namespace,resources"

I need to split above parameter into two text boxes on click checkbox. like
namespace as label and textbox, resource as label and textbox

Please help, Thank you.
Html:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let product of DisplayProductList">
                                    <label class="form-check-label text-break">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" formControlName="templateparameter" [value]="true"
                                  [(ngModel)]="product.isChecked" (change)="changeSelection($event)"> {{ product.template_name }}
                                  <span class="form-check-sign">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                  </span>
                                </label>
                                </div>
```

ts:

```
 changeSelection(event: any) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {
       
        if (product.isChecked == true) {
          return product.isChecked

        }
       
      }
      );
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add some code to your question, what did you try until now?

Comment: I have added my code there, When i check my checkbox, the value is coming, but i need to split that value into text boxes. like values as lables.

Answer (score 0):

The below line would give you  label1 & label2 as parameters.

```
let  [ label1, label2 ] =  template_parameter.split(',');
```

You can add and remove from-control dynamically as required on the selection of checkbox

```
this.yourForm.addControl(label1, new FormControl('', Validators.required));
this.yourForm.removeControl(label1);
```

In the HTML you can simply check if these forms exist so you can show them when needed.

```
 *ngIf="yourForm.contains(controlName: string)"
```

Comment: Thank you @Vaira for your response, I have done that in an other way.It worked.